# Pick elements on (un)even index from an array in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a Groovy array containing digits of a number. I need to create two new arrays containing only the digits at even resp. uneven positions from that array.

The best way that I could find is this, but I feel there's quite a lot of room for improvement here:

```
def evenDigits = digits
    .indexed(1)
    .findAll { i, v -> i % 2 == 0 }
    .collect { it.value }
```

Obviously the `unevenDigits` variant would be to simply check the modulus in the `findAll` closure against `1` instead of `0`.

Does anyone know if this code can be improved or compacted?

Comment: For golfs sake: `.collect{ it.value }` is just `.values()`.

Comment: @cfrick Oh boy, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A "less smarter" (and definitely more performant) solution:

```
def evens = [], odds = []
digits.eachWithIndex{ v, ix -> ( ix & 1 ? odds : evens ) << v }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `groupBy` to separate the results to odd/even items.  E.g.

```
groovy:000> ["a","b","c"].indexed(1).groupBy{ i, _ -> i & 1 }.collectEntries{ k, v -> [k as Boolean, v.values()] }
===> [true:[a, c], false:[b]]
```

Comment: It didn't necessarily have to be in one statement. This solution looks smarter but also harder to figure out what is happening.

Comment: I like `a & 1` over `a % 2` check

Comment: @injecteer It is probably faster indeed, but performance is not gonna be an issue (12 digits, a couple of executions a day).

Comment: @Koen indeed. I'm looking at a bigger picture for use-cases with 10k rps

Answer (score 1):

One more "Groovy" solution that uses `withIndex()` and `findResults()` combination.

- `withIndex()` transforms a `List<T>` to `List<Tuple2<T,Integer>>` - a list of value-index tuples.
- `findResults(closure)` runs filtering transformation - the closure it receives is a transforming predicate. In our case, it checks if the index value is odd or even and extracts the value from tuple if the predicate matches. (All `null` values are filtered out.)

Short and concise. Requires a minimal number of transformations: `List<T>` to `List<Tuple2<T,Integer>>` and then a single iteration to produce the final result.

```groovy
def numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,1] // Some test data

def even = { t -> t.second % 2 == 0 ? t.first : null } // "Even" transforming predicate
def odd = { t -> t.second % 2 == 1 ? t.first : null } // "Odd" transforming predicate

def evens = numbers.withIndex(1).findResults even
def odds = numbers.withIndex(1).findResults odd

// And some assertions to test the implementation
assert evens == [2,4,6,3]
assert odds == [1,3,5,2,1]
```

Comment: I guess I prefer `findAll` using a boolean returning closure over `findResults` returning the value or `null`. I also prefer `indexed` over `withIndex` but that is all personal taste I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, for a single pass (but still with the intermediate collection due to `indexed`), would be a reduce:

```
def (odd,even) = digits.indexed().inject([[],[]]){ acc, it -> acc[it.key&1] << it.value; acc }
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort and you deserve the upvote, but I can't pass this on to a fellow developer to maintain this.

Comment: You put this in a function, give it a proper name, document the behaviour in some tests and you are done.  With the reduce it's basically like the groupBy but without shaping the data again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, but it's probably not the cleverest way.

```
    def isEven = { int x -> x % 2 == 0 ? x : null}

    def (digits, evens, odds) = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [], []] 

    digits.each { 
        if (isEven(it))
            evens.add(isEven(it))
    }

    odds = digits - evens 

    assert evens == [2, 4, 6, 8]
    assert odds == [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: My mistake, I didn't mean the even or uneven digits, but the digits at even and uneven positions. Question updated.